# How to use MP3Sharp with IFormFile

Tags: c#, mp3, filestream

I want to convert an mp3 file to pcm using MP3Sharp (https://github.com/ZaneDubya/MP3Sharp) in a web app, where the mp3 file is passed in as IFormFile

It works if I save the file to disk first like this ...

```
                using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream("file.mp3", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                MP3Stream stream = new MP3Stream("file.mp3");
```

... but when I try to do it as a stream without writing to file it doesn't work:

```
                using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    MP3Stream stream = new MP3Stream(fileStream);
                }
```

The MP3Stream constructor throws this exception:

MP3Sharp.MP3SharpException: 'Unhandled channel count rep: -1 (allowed values are 1-mono and 2-stereo).'

... Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your code does `file.CopyToAsync(fileStream)`, the *MemoryStream*'s read/write position is pointing after the written MP3 data at the **end of the *MemoryStream***.

The *MP3Stream* then trying to read from the *MemoryStream* will only notice that the end of the *MemoryStream* has been reached (because its read/write position is already at the end) and throws an exception.<sup>[1]</sup>

Thus, after copying the MP3 data into the *MemoryStream*, set the *MemoryStream*'s read/write position back to where it was before you copied the MP3 data into it (in the case of your example code it's the beginning of the *MemoryStream*, position 0):

```
await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
fileStream.Position = 0;
```

Side note: Like *FileStream* and *MemoryStream*, *MP3Stream* is also a *Stream* and therefore an *IDisposable*, too. And like you already did with the *FileStream* and the *MemoryStream*, you should use the `using` statement for the *MP3Stream* as well.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The exception you got from the MP3Sharp library is misleading, and as such is kind of a bug in the library. Because, when attempting to read a byte from a stream and the stream is at its end, the *Stream.ReadByte* method will return -1 to indicate end-of-stream. And as apparent by the exception message, it seems the MP3Sharp library does not properly treat the -1 value here as simply meaning "*the end of the stream has been reached and no (further) data could be read*" and misinterprets it as a channel count value.